# Creating a QPOINTS File for Phonon Calculations in VASP

Tags: vasp, phonon-dispersion, q-points

How to construct a QPOINTS file for phonon calculations in VASP, and when is it employed instead of KPOINTS during a VASP standard run for phonon calculations? Could anyone also provide the preferred format style for specifying q-points in the QPOINTS file?

Comment: See https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LPHON_DISPERSION for when you use it (in addition to KPOINTS, not instead of KPOINTS - you probably always need a KPOINTS file). Format of QPOINTS is same as KPOINTS https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/QPOINTS.

Comment: @CWTan Thank you for your answer but i am confused  there are two formats for KPOINTS one has  regular mesh and  other has k points along high symmetry lines
used for bands structure.which format should i use?

Comment: In the LPHON_DISPERSION page, it says "LPHON_DISPERSION requests the calculation of the phonon dispersion along the q-point path supplied in file QPOINTS (same format as KPOINTS)." So you should be specifying the k points along high symmetry lines if you want to use the LPHON_DISPERSION tag to produce phonon bandstructure data for a bandstructure plot. You'd want a regular mesh for phonon DOS, but I'm not sure if VASP offers that functionality (you can always use the Phonopy interface to VASP for general phonon calculations).

Comment: @CWTan i used k points along high symmetry lines for both KPOINTS and QPOINTS but when i run vasp_std it does not execute?

Comment: Assuming you just want to get a phonon bandstructure, you should use "k points along high symmetry lines" for QPOINTS, but a regular mesh for KPOINTS. You would use a "k points along high symmetry lines" for KPOINTS if you wanted an electronic bandstructure.